# total custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

hello in this plugin i write this 2 code total post for cpt1 and cpt2 now i want code to get total of this 2 CPT Custom post type /// that means // menha_dir_ltg + mobadra1_dir_ltg = ??? any idea

```
//this is to count totala custom post -- mobadra2_dir_ltg - ta7tag da3m
add_shortcode('total-listing-counter-menha','total_listing_counterـmenha');
function total_listing_counterـmenha(){
 $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'menha_dir_ltg' )->publish;
 return $count_posts;
}
//this is to count totala custom post -- mobadra1_dir_ltg - ta7tag da3m
add_shortcode('total-listing-counter-ta7tag-da3m','total_listing_counterـta7tagـda3m');
function total_listing_counterـta7tagـda3m(){
 $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'mobadra1_dir_ltg' )->publish;
 return $count_posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply combine the two in a third shortcode and update a "$total_count" variable:

```
add_shortcode('total-listing-counter','total_listing_counter');

function total_listing_counter(){

     $count_menha_dir_ltg_posts = wp_count_posts( 'menha_dir_ltg' )->publish;
     $count_mobadra1_dir_ltg_posts = wp_count_posts( 'mobadra1_dir_ltg' )->publish;
     $total_count = count_menha_dir_ltg_posts + $count_mobadra1_dir_ltg_posts;

     return $total_count;

}
```

Comment: please can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282871/custom-field-counting-wordpress

Comment: Ahmed, you simply do the same as above; combine the two WP_Query in a shortcode and update a "$total_count" variable. Remember to wp_reset_postdata() after each while loop.